# Using class binding to activate routerLink in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to add active class to routerLink in Angular 6.My sidnav component consist of all routerLinks. After clicking on routerlink that particular link should be active and the particular component should appear.I tried using focus css,it  is working when I click on Link 2 times.May be I am getting error because I am use sidenav selector in bill-to component.

sidenav component html Code:

```
 <li ><a  [ngClass]="{'red-input':clicked}" routerLink="/bill-to" routerLinkActive="red-input" (click)="Clicked()" >Bill To</a></li>
<li ><a   [ngClass]="{'red-input':clicked}" routerLink="/ship-to" routerLinkActive="red-input"  (click)="Clicked()"> Ship To</a></li>
```

ts code:

```
 clicked: boolean = false;

 Clicked() {
this.clicked = true;
 }
```

Bill-to component code:

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
     <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>       
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-8" style="margin-top:1%;">

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's what routerLinkActive does all by itself. Remove the [ngClass] and the (click) handler: they're useless.

Comment: I removed it ,still not working

Comment: Define "not working", precisely. If you get an error, post it, of course. Why do you have a sidenav inside the bill-to component? It makes no sense. The sidenav allows displaying it, so it's already displayed outseid of this component.

Comment: not-working : Working after clicking 2 times on link.

Comment: not-working : Working after clicking 2 times on link.I am using sidenav inside bill-to component because ,I am using sidenav(parent compnent) second time in this project.This sidenav is not considered inside routeroutlet thus I used sidenav inside bill-to component

Comment: I have no idea why you would want the sidenav displayed twice in the same page. It's very unclear. Post a stackblitz reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `[routerLinkActive]="'your-class-name'"`. It will detect if route is active and apply class by itself.

**DEMO**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gyhshq

Comment: Can I use router-outlet 2 times in same project?

Comment: @kedarkulk of course you can. https://angular.io/guide/router#child-routing-component

Comment: Do we need to create different routing module fot that

Comment: @kedarkulk no you don't however you need to define child routes.